# jfreechart, how to paint a graph transparently black

Tags: java, jfreechart

The provided link (this is the result I need) demonstrates the desired result. To achieve this, I tried to access the X y chart graph and set its background coloring to a semi-transparent color using the following code:

`val plot = chart.getXYPlot(); plot.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(0x4D575656, true));`

[The result that came out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCMMU.png)
I tried this, but it turns out [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PowA.png)

Comment: that is, it colored only the graph, but without the values themselves on the left and bottom

Comment: Have you tried an implementation of `Paint` that has a _gradient_?

Comment: Yes, I used it for the color of the graph, but how does this relate to the creation of a black transparent square?

Comment: Honesty, I don't think I understand the question; in the hope that someone does, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your current approach.

Comment: Also, review the _gallery of sample charts_, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info).